# dompdf font family issue

Tags: dompdf, font-family

I'm using Bamboo invoice as an invoice generator, and I'm trying to customize the invoice template, but no matter what I do, the font just won't seem to adjust.

currently I have

```
body {
margin: 0.5in;
font-family: 'helvetica';
font-size: 10pt;}
```

I've read up on it, and helvetica is an installed font, so it should work

to make sure I changed it to 'courier'; which is also in the lib/fonts directory, but the font remains the same.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Kinda late, but still applicable for google visitors*

I had a similar problem with DomPDF, but since BambooInvoice uses it... Anyway DomPDF has trouble with the font-family definition in the CSS. I applied inline style to the top div box to solve the problem.

```
<div id="container" style="font-family:sans-serif;">
....
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by removing a `font: inherit` that was applied as a 'css-reset' to almost all elements as a first declariation. Apparently this is not overridden by later declarations, and/or inherit doesn't work properly.

Comment: Thanks, a very small isuue that took me a couple of days to understand and find. But seems that domPdf  was looking for a font family inherit.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with DomPDF 6b3 when trying to use *font-family* or *font-size*. Finally discovered that using *font* instead of those seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `helvetica`.