# domPdf open sans font issue

Tags: dompdf

I am usign dompdf with a custom font family - open sans from google fonts

I hae the font locally and set a CSS font face rule.
On my local env (windows) the font on the PDF is working as expected but on the testing enviroment (Linux) it is not loading the custom font and seems to use default font.

Tried setting it manually, tried installing it by load_font.php script, verifies that the folders are writable.

I am out of ideas and any help would be appreciated.

This is my CSS part:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.svg#OpenSans-Regular') format('svg'),
   url('/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('http://app.dev.predictix.net/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
   url('/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');



  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually on the CSS Reset code i have on the page.
On the reset  code i had:

```
font:inherit
```

DomPdf took that as the font family and was searching for a font family of inherit and this is why it was not loading my font. Once i disabled that css reset rule my font was disblayed as needed.

Thanks also to @Ewout that give me some direction here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20044474/2022193

Comment: This may have been addressed by a change made starting with v0.8.1. Which release are you using?

Comment: @BrianS i am using version 0.8.3

Comment: This may be an inheritance issue. Is the `font: inherit` declaration on the global selector (*)? I found that if I added the font-family declaration using the selector for the element containing the text, or if I used the global selector, the correct font was used.

Comment: I went ahead and created an issue for this: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1897